# How to test if an event produces behaviour changes?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

im learning and im curious about to know if an event generate behaviour changes in messagery application usage.
In this case, the hours in which an users gets online for chatting, and the hours this user receives a call.
I want to know if those calls reduces/increases the times the user uses the chat, or changes its frequent hours, or anykind of behaviour change. Just to research if calls affects chatting habits.

For this purpose, ive gathered two years of chat (whatsapp) logs, in which appears the hour I get online. I also have call logs, which shows the date/time of the calls.

My question is, which is the right approach for this? 
Correlations may not work cause not everyday i receive calls. Also, chatting habits are not fully stable...
Ive been thinking about hyphotesis contrasts, but not sure about how to focus it...

Statistically speaking, how whould you approach this? which techniques do you recommend?

Comment: This sounds like a job for linear regression.

Comment: I'd first plot mean chat times in-between each call, with +- std errorbar, to see if there is a trend. Also, plot these means vs call times.